# How is the method Total being called in this example

Tags: vuejs2

I see in the code below how the list item's class and state is being modified but I don't understand where or how the total() method is being triggered. The total is added to the markup in the `<span>{{total() | currency}}</span>` but there is no click event or anything reactive that I see in the code that is bound to it.

```
<template>

    <!-- v-cloak hides any un-compiled data bindings until the Vue instance is ready. -->
    <form id="main" v-cloak>

        <h1>Services</h1>

        <ul>
            <!-- Loop through the services array, assign a click handler, and set or
                remove the "active" css class if needed -->
            <li 
                v-for="service in services" 
                v-bind:key="service.id" 
                v-on:click="toggleActive(service)" 
                v-bind:class="{ 'active': service.active}">
                <!-- Display the name and price for every entry in the array .
                    Vue.js has a built in currency filter for formatting the price -->
                {{service.name}} <span>{{service.price | currency}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="total">
            <!-- Calculate the total price of all chosen services. Format it as currency. -->
            Total: <span>{{total() | currency}}</span>
        </div>

    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'OrderForm',
    data(){
        return{
        // Define the model properties. The view will loop
        // through the services array and genreate a li
        // element for every one of its items.
        services: [
            {
                name: 'Web Development',
                price: 300,
                active:true
            },{
                name: 'Design',
                price: 400,
                active:false
            },{
                name: 'Integration',
                price: 250,
                active:false
            },{
                name: 'Training',
                price: 220,
                active:false
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    // Functions we will be using.
    methods: {
        toggleActive: function(s){
            s.active = !s.active;
        },
        total: function(){

            var total = 0;

            this.services.forEach(function(s){
                if (s.active){
                    total+= s.price;
                }
            });

           return total;
        }
    },
    filters: {
        currency: function(value) {
            return '$' + value.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

EDIT:

Working example 
https://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/5-practical-examples-for-learning-vue-js

Comment: Are you saying it works?  As far as I can tell it would be called when the component is mounted/rendered, but without a watcher to call the  method again it would not be reactive.

Comment: Yes this is working you can see the live example #3 Order Form, https://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/5-practical-examples-for-learning-vue-js. I copied the exact code to my local environment and it works just like the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the data, the template in the components rerendered. That means that the template will trigger all methods bind to the templates. You can see it by adding dynamic date for example.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment by 1</button>
  <p>{{total()}}</p>
  <p>
  // Date will be updated after clicking on increment:
  {{date()}}
  </p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        counter: 0,
  },
  methods: {
        increment: function(){
            this.counter += 1;    
    },
    total: function(){
      return this.counter;
    },
    date: function() {
      return new Date();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: So, there isn't a specific binding between toggleActive() and total() but when you click on a list item which calls the toggleActive method this refreshes the template/markup so everything gets refreshed (methods within the markup get called again), really am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: There is no binding between toggleActive and total. On component update cycle,  rendering of the template will be triggered and data methods that are bound to a template will be triggered as well.

Comment: Mitro,  your code example does not even make sense.  What is the `counter` property and `total()` method being used for?   You simply came and copied and pasted the code from my answers example and then added the `date` method without even bothering to remove the unused code.  Knocking off someone elses answer is not a very good way to be welcomed to a community.

Comment: Also it is not true that Vuejs rerenders a components template simply when the the data is updated.  Doing so would cause it to be very resource intensive.   Vue automatically creates getters and setters for each property and adds any thing touched during the render to its watcher instance.  Your example with the date function would not work if you removed the total method.  Which shows it is not simply the data changing that causes re rendering, but the total method that is bound to the reactive instance. https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/yq4moz2e/12/

Comment: Your example above isn't working because you don't have {{counter}} inside your template so, there is no binding between. When you put {{ counter }} (https://jsfiddle.net/zvy2r0ge/1/), template will be rerendered and trigger date function. I didn't copy your answer, my point in the answer is different then yours.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe the explanation for what is happening is that data's `services` object is reactive. Since the `total` method is being bound to it, when the `toggleActive` method is being called, it is updating `services` which causes the `total` method to also be called.

From the docs here '**How Changes Are Tracked**' https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

> Every component instance has a corresponding watcher instance, which records any properties “touched” during the component’s render as dependencies. Later on when a dependency’s setter is triggered, it notifies the watcher, which in turn causes the component to re-render.

Often I find simplifying what is going on helps me understand it. If you did a very simplified version of above it might look like this.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment by 1</button>
  <p>{{total()}}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
  },
  methods: {
   increment: function(){
     this.counter += 1;    
   },
   total: function(){
    return this.counter;
   }
  }
})
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/yq4moz2e/10/

If you simplify it even further by putting the data property `counter` in the template, when its value changes, you would naturally expect the value in the template to also be updated. So this should help you understand why the `total` method gets called.

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="increment">Increment by 1</button>
  <p>{{counter}}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
    counter: 0,
   },
   methods: {
      increment: function(){
         this.counter += 1;    
      },
   }
})
```

working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/yq4moz2e/6/